# ProblemDetails response does not contain TraceId property

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, .net-7.0

I am trying to setup .NET [ProblemDetails Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-7.0#problem-details-service)

I have following code in  **Program.cs**

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddProblemDetails();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// ProblemDetails related middlewares
app.UseExceptionHandler();
app.UseStatusCodePages();
```

Than I have simple endpoint throwing an exception

```cs
[Route("api/suppliers")]
public IActionResult Get()
{
     var x = 0;
     var y = 1 / x; // throws divide by zero exception
     var suppliers = _context.Suppliers.ToList();
     return Ok(suppliers);
}
```

I switched environment variable to production and when I hit the endpoint in browser I am getting the following response

```json
{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.6.1","title":"An error occurred while processing your request.","status":500}
```

Why I do not see **trace-id** or **request-id** identifier? How to enhance the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code solved the issue and it seems to work.

```
builder.Services.AddProblemDetails(options =>
    options.CustomizeProblemDetails = (context) =>
    {
        if (!context.ProblemDetails.Extensions.ContainsKey("traceId"))
        { 
            string? traceId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? context.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
            context.ProblemDetails.Extensions.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object?>("traceId", traceId));
        }
    }
);
```

response

```
{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.6.1","title":"An error occurred while processing your request.","status":500,"traceId":"00-6cc3ae3a36c257be2cec5f41a765b3c9-3806c931361744ed-00"}
```